# Firebase cloud functions onCreate painfully slow to update database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having a slightly odd issue, and due to the lack of errors, I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. What I am trying to do is on an `onCreate` event, make an API call, and then update a field on the database if the field is not set to `null`. Based on my console logs for cloud functions, I can see the API call getting a `ok`, and everything is working properly, but after about 2-5 minutes, it will update. A few times, it didnt update after 15 mins. What is causing such a slow update?

I have eliminated the `gaxios` call as the bottleneck simply from the functions logs, and local testing.

Some context: I am on the firebase blaze plan to allow for egress and my dataset isnt really big. I am using `gaxios` because it is already part of firebase-funcstions npm install.

The code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { request } = require('gaxios');
const { parse } = require('url');

exports.getGithubReadme = functions.firestore.document('readmes/{name}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const toolName = context.params.name;
    console.log(toolName);
    const { name, description, site } = snapshot.data();
    console.log(name, description, site);

    const parsedUrl = parse(site);
    console.log(parsedUrl);

    if (description) return;

    if (parsedUrl.hostname === 'github.com') {
        let githubUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos${parsedUrl.path}/readme`;
        request({
            method : 'GET',
            url    : githubUrl
        })
            .then((res) => {
                let { content } = res.data;
                return snapshot.ref.update({ description: content });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            });
    }
    return null;
});
```

[image: Screenshot showing 2 minutes to update]

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  Right now you are just returning null in all circumstances, which means that the function isn't waiting at all for completion, and it could be shut down immediately after it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute an asynchronous operation (i.e. `request()` in your case) in a background triggered Cloud Function, **you must return a promise**, in such a way the Cloud Function waits that this promise resolves in order to terminate.

This is very well explained in the official Firebase video series here ([Learning Cloud Functions for Firebase (video series)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/)). In particular watch the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" (Parts 2 & 3 especially focus on background triggered Cloud Functions, but it really worth watching Part 1 before).

So you should adapt your code as follows, returning the promise returned by `request()`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { request } = require('gaxios');
const { parse } = require('url');

exports.getGithubReadme = functions.firestore.document('readmes/{name}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const toolName = context.params.name;
    console.log(toolName);
    const { name, description, site } = snapshot.data();
    console.log(name, description, site);

    const parsedUrl = parse(site);
    console.log(parsedUrl);

    if (description) return null;

    if (parsedUrl.hostname === 'github.com') {
        let githubUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos${parsedUrl.path}/readme`;
        return request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: githubUrl
        })
        .then((res) => {
            let { content } = res.data;
            return snapshot.ref.update({ description: content });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }

});
```

Comment: I get it! I missed the `you must return a promise` when scanning through the docs. Thanks!