# Firebase cloud function taking too much time to update database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a simple cloud function that triggers when any new document is created in the orders collection. After which I want to loop through the "test" collection and update the name for each document to "Harry". But it is taking 5 minutes or more to update the database. Am I missing something?

Code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


exports.onCreateOrder = functions.firestore.document('PPB/{id}/Orders/{order_id}').onCreate( async (snapshot,context) => {
  var userRef = db.collection('test');
  userRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
         doc.ref.update({"name" : "Harry"});
        });
       return "success";
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        return "error";
    });
  }

);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [requirement to return a promise from the function that resolves only after all async work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  It's crucial to understand how promises work with Cloud Functions in order to write correct code.

Simply calling `then` and `catch` are not sufficient. They do not pause execution of the code - they are merely callbacks for async work.  As of right now, you are ignoring the promise returned from `catch`, as well as all the promises returned by the calls to `update()`.  This means that the function terminates immediately without waiting for the work to complete, and that work might or might not actually complete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push all the promises to a array and use Promise.all() to wait for all the calls to be finished.

```
exports.onCreateOrder = functions.firestore.document('PPB/{id}/Orders/{order_id}').onCreate( async (snapshot,context) => {
  return db.collection('test').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const promise = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
         promise.push(db.collection('test').doc(doc.id).update({"name" : "Harry"}));
        });
        return Promise.all(promise)
    })
    .then(snapshot => {
       return "success";
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        return "error";
    });
  }

);
```

Comment: still not updating the database

Answer (score 0):

The above issue mainly occurs when promises are not being handled properly in the Cloud Functions code, so make sure you handle it correctly.
In your code, promises returned from the catch() and update() both are not handled correctly. In order to make your function successfully completed, promises should be resolved so that it will not terminate the function without completing the work.

Syntax :

```
const Promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('new');
  }, 300);
});

Promise1
  .then(Resolved1, Rejected1)
  .then(Resolved2, Rejected2)
  .then(Resolved3, Rejected3);
```

For reference you can check out this stackoverflow [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597475/firebase-cloud-functions-oncreate-painfully-slow-to-update-database) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508842/firebase-cloud-function-taking-over-5-minutes-to-update-database) where a similar issue has been resolved by the community members  by making sure that you return a promise in such a way that the Cloud Functions wait until this promise resolves to terminate.
You can refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for further knowledge on promises.

Comment: @ali262883 Posted an answer, Is it helpful?